# Script to change the amount of divisions on bevels or cylinders

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to create a script that adds divisions to loops of faces which would be handy for changing the resolution of things like bevels and cylinders. My script is applying a subdivide and then doing a smooth verts with the smooth direction based on the face normals of the selection.

***Edit, so I worked on this a bit. 
[image]

Now it functions a bit better, but it has 
two problems due to the way that smooth verts works:

1.)Edges on the bevel don't smooth evenly because the geometry is usually longer at the end of the selection. This might be solved by deselecting the two edges before smoothing, but as of now, I don't really know how to solve that.

[image]

2.)Geometry that has angles will appear to smooth in the omitted smoothing direction a little bit. For example, the selections in this gif are all smoothing along x and y, but when you smooth something at an angle, it moves the vertices along z too.  I suppose this is just the way smooth works, but there needs to be a way to stop it. I tried smoothing rows of verts individually, but it seems that it introduced some angle changes. I really need a better idea here.

```
    import bpy
import bmesh
# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
selected_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
selected_edges = [e for e in bm.edges if e.select]


"""
get the edges to subdivide based on euler
allow tolerance for 45 deg edges and
add all boundary edges
"""
divide_edges = []
for i in selected_edges:
    if not i.is_boundary:
        face_angle = i.calc_face_angle()
        if face_angle > 0.75 or face_angle == 0.0:
            divide_edges.append(i)
    elif i.is_boundary:
        divide_edges.append(i)


"""
Find the smoothing axis
if an axis repeats many times
set the axis to false
"""
x_values = []
y_values = []
z_values = []
for f in selected_faces:
    x_values.append(f.normal[0])
    y_values.append(f.normal[1])
    z_values.append(f.normal[2])

def simliar_face_normals(normal):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(normal)-1):
        if normal[i] == normal[i+1]:
            counter = counter + 1
    return counter

normals_amount = [simliar_face_normals(x_values), simliar_face_normals(y_values), simliar_face_normals(z_values)]
smoothing_direction = []
for n in range(len(normals_amount)):
    if normals_amount[n] == max(normals_amount):
        smoothing_direction.append(False)
    else:
        smoothing_direction.append(True)



#subdivide the selection
cut_edges = bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm, edges=divide_edges, use_grid_fill=True, cuts=1)
bm.select_flush(False)
#get the verts from the subdivide
geom_smooth = cut_edges["geom"]
verts_smooth = [ele for ele in geom_smooth
                if isinstance(ele, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
selected_verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]


bmesh.ops.smooth_vert(bm, verts=verts_smooth + selected_verts, factor=0.5, use_axis_x=smoothing_direction[0], use_axis_y=smoothing_direction[1], use_axis_z=smoothing_direction[2])


#select all changes and commit mesh
for v in verts_smooth + selected_verts:
    v.select = True
bm.select_flush(True)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: Haven't checked your script in details, but the more you subdivide here, the less the angle between two faces is high.

Comment: @lemon yeah, I'm wondering if there's a better way, like comparing the amount of edges in the loops? I'm not really sure how to do that though. The real problem comes when finding the direction to smooth it, I just don't have a good answer for that.

Comment: For the deselect outer edges maybe something like `not all(f.select for f in edge.link_faces)`  Can I also suggest that for some boolean variable `var` can simply use `if var: else:` rather than `if var == True: elif var == False:`  ... and `for e in selected_edges:` removes the need to enumerate and index.  Might also need to investigate updating normals after an op.

Comment: I edited my script based on your suggestions, they're very helpful. I was able to deselect based on ```not all(f.select for f in edge.link_faces)```, but I tried to store all the verts for the smooth operation in a list like this: ```c_edge = []
for e in bm.edges:
    for f in e.link_faces:
        if not f.select:
            c_edge.append(e.verts)``` This returns a BMElemSeq and I can't really convert it to a list of verts for the smooth operator. I'm also a bit confused as to why I can put everything in a list and it appears to handle things like a dict? It was why I was enumerating.

Comment: Ah, I kind of have an answer. I just realized BMElemSeq is another list of verts edges or faces. So if I get a list of BMElemSeq from link_faces, I just have to iterate over each item in that list. Is that the correct way to think of it? A list within a list?